# Node.js - eventListener - How to log in a file while triggering an event

Tags: javascript, node.js, tcp, event-listener

I saw on the [node.js documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_event_exit) that "Listener functions must only perform synchronous operations".
But, when i tried to use fs.writeFileSync, it doesn't works :

```
net.createServer(function (socket)
{
    [...]

    socket.on('error', (err) => {
         **fs.writeFileSync('C:\temp\test.txt', err.message);**
         console.log('Connection error:', err.message);
    });
}).listen(port);
```

Maybe I didn't understand something ?

The console.log just allows my script to not crash when the socket is abruptly closed, for example, due to an RST sent by a Load Balancer.
In production, I need to trace in a file when i get an error from the listening port (using TCP). But if I add the fs.writeFileSync line, my script keeps crashing and I don't get any log in my file. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This quote from the documentation only applies to the event that it describes - `process.on('exit')`:

> Listener functions must only perform synchronous operations. The Node.js process will exit immediately after calling the 'exit' event listeners causing any additional work still queued in the event loop to be abandoned.

This is not a general statement - you can trigger asynchronous operations in event listeners just fine (but note that the EventEmitter will not wait for your async work to finish - so be wary of concurrency issues). For logging, consider opening a file just once and appending to avoid additional overhead.

Usually, a logging library can take care of this for you. For example, [winston](https://www.npmjs.com/package/winston) can write directly to files. A popular alternative approach is to just log everything to *stdout* using a more light-weight library such as [pino](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pino), and run Node.js under a process supervisor such as PM2 or docker that already captures the standard output and writes it to a file automatically.

Comment: Hello,

Thank you for your answer. Indeed I had not understood that it was only on this event. Although my script kept crashing using alternatives to this event.

After many tries to install winston (because of an existing node.js a bit wobbly - without npm, don't ask me why), it finally seems to work as I wanted. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Glad it helped. Please mark the answer as accepted if you found it useful - it indicates to other users that it worked and they can follow the advice.